# How to traverse fixed number of elements in c++ list

Tags: c++, stl

I want to traverse a list in C++ but only till fifth from last not till the end.
But I see that there is no "-" operator defined so that I could use

```
list<>::iterator j=i-5;
```

I can do it using `size()` function somehow keeping counts etc but is there any other direct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count is the only practical way that may not involve effectively traversing the list in some way.

```
auto myEnd = std::advance(myList.end(),-5)
```

but this will just traverse the last five list elements to get to your desired point, so its no faster or more elegant than most other solutions. However, using an integer loop does require keeping both an integer count and an iterator, this really only requires the iterator so in that regard it may be nicer.

If your `<list>` has an O(1) count, and the distance back from end is large, use an integer loop, else the above is nice.

Comment: nice answer, can you just fix the name of the name space in your code.`std::` instead of `st::`

Answer (score 4):

List doesn't support random access iterators. You can use reverse iterator and counter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to get the iterator to the fifth from last.

Comment: It worth doing if you need data only for 5th element. Otherwise it is double work from performance point of view.

Comment: You speak about performance, ok. Nevertheless there exist a function called `std::advance` that does the job. And if one doesn't not want double work, one can use reverse iterator in combination with std::advance.

Comment: you dont need a reverse iterator, advance takes negative values.

Comment: I mean you first find end element and then you put this element into loop as exit condition. It might be not optimal in general case. For five elements it doesn't matter though.

Comment: @sonofthenortherndarkness Nevertheless, there exists a function called `std::advance` that does the job. Maybe not always optimal, however there exist a c++ function.

Comment: @StephaneRolland sure. no question about that.

Answer (score 1):

The list has bidirectional iterator. So that to get the fifth iterator from the end iterator you should 5 times apply operation -- that is defined for bidirectional iterators. The C++ Standard provides two functions that perform this task. The first one that appeared in C++ 2003 is std::advance. The second one that appeared in C++ 2011 is std::prev. It is simpler to use the second function, std::prev, because it returns the needed iterator. For example

```
std::list<int> l = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::copy( l.begin(), std::prev( l.end(), 5 ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the available answers, I'd recommend sticking to a standard algorithm for traversing the list rather than dealing with iterators directly; if you can avoid it.

For example:

```
auto l = list<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
for_each(begin(l), prev(end(l), 5), [](const int& i) {
    cout << i << endl;
});
```

http://ideone.com/6wNuMP